# Remove jQuery function when shrinking screen

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-masonry, unbind

Pretty sure this has been asked before, might just be struggling with terminology, but I can't find a good answer so here goes!

I have a jQuery masonry function that I only want to kick in above a certain screen size (819px). This is easy enough to do, the issue comes when the screen is resized, going up the way is fine, however shrinking the screen causes some issues as the function remains in-place breaking the layout.

How do I remove a functions actions when the screen goes back down below 820px?

Current code is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CvJDc

Any ideas? Questions?

Thanks in advance.....!

Comment: it seems that there is no problem when upsizing the page. If you start from a tiny page and expend it, it allways finish with a good rendering. The problem only occurs when downsizing the screen. May be a clue...

Comment: Sorry for double post... have you played with this ? http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/htsui

Comment: I'm aware the issue only occurs when sizing down from load, hence the question! I have seen that codepen but didn't see anything that really helped to be honest....

Comment: Can you try to refresh the mansonry after having dowsized the screen ?  I 've looked for a refresh function in mansonry. It seems that calling it again make this. `$("#container").mansonry();`